# Pygame error: File is not a Windows BMP file - Mac os x 10.11.4

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame, anaconda

I managed to install Pygame but I think I messed something up because when I just try to do :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((800,533), RESIZABLE)
fond = pygame.image.load("img/Ciel_bleu.jpg").convert()
fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

It says :

> error: File is not a Windows BMP file

I am very sorry to bother you with that problem but I really tried for weeks to search for a solution and I don't know what to do... I looked up a lot of posts talking about this error but I can't solve it..
By the way I'm on Mac os x 10.11.4 and I used Anaconda to install Python 2.7.10.
Here is [the results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ottjg8syzbjaf3/run_tests%20results.txt?dl=0) when I run the "python run_tests.py" file from [the Pygame source code folder.](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz)

I would be very glad and grateful if someone could help me.
Many thanks in advance for your help, have a great day !

(excuse my English)

Comment: Here is [the results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ottjg8syzbjaf3/run_tests%20results.txt?dl=0) when I run the "python run_tests.py" file from the Pygame [source code folder.](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz)

Comment: As per http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html, "By default it can only load uncompressed BMP images. When built with full image support, the pygame.image.load() function can support the following formats.

        JPG
        PNG
        GIF (non animated)
        BMP
        PCX
        TGA (uncompressed)
        TIF
        LBM (and PBM)
        PBM (and PGM, PPM)
        XPM"

Comment: @JoseGómez Many thanks for your respond ! But where and how can I install the "full image support" ?

Comment: Matrixko: see my response; I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As per [pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html), "By default it can only load uncompressed BMP images. When built with full image support, the pygame.image.load() function can support the following formats. JPG PNG GIF (non animated) BMP PCX TGA (uncompressed) TIF LBM (and PBM) PBM (and PGM, PPM) XPM".

As per [Build Pygame with full image support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365060/build-pygame-with-full-image-support), you can get the image module here: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil

Comment: I already have PIL installed correctly and working... Do you have another Idea ? Thanks for your time by the way

Answer (score 1):

Give [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492863/install-pygame-in-anaconda/710086) a try:

Install binstar:

`conda install binstar`

You get a response like: The 'binstar' conda package has been renamed to 'anaconda-client'. Please run: conda install anaconda-client. So run:

`conda install anaconda-client`

Then search for the pygame package on anaconda.org:

`anaconda search -t conda pygame`

You get a list of pygame packages available at anaconda.org. Select a package for your distribution e.g. tlatorre/pygame is for Linux 64-bit. To install it use:

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/tlatorre pygame`

Once done, import pygame should work.

Credit: Answer by cohdez on [Installing pygame module in anaconda mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137369/installing-pygame-module-in-anaconda-mac)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is updated pygame https://conda.binstar.org/quasiben to https://conda.binstar.org/CogSci.

Once done, import pygame should work.